# What is file descriptor 47 used for?

Tags: bash, zsh, kde, file-descriptors

I have noticed that when I run

```
ls /proc/self/fd
```

I get the following output:

```
0  1  2  3  47
```

Obviously, `0`, `1` and `2` are the descriptors for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively, and `3` is the descriptor which `ls` uses to access the directory.

But what is `47`? It must be something passed by the shell (and not something specific to `ls`) because running `cat` outputs:

```
$ cat /proc/self/fd/47
cat: /proc/self/fd/47: Permission denied

# example of running cat on a non-existent file descriptor
$ cat /proc/self/fd/46
cat: /proc/self/fd/46: No such file or directory
```

`ls -l` says that it is connected to `anon_inode:inotify`.

I am using Arch Linux with KDE, and this seems to matter, because it doesn't seem to happen if I run commands from tty. It's not shell specific (it happens on both `bash` and `zsh`), though it may be terminal specific (I am using Konsole). Regardless, isn't the shell supposed to close every descriptor except 0-2 before exec (or have them flagged with `O_CLOEXEC`)?

I am running KDE Plasma 5.27.10.

EDIT: Since `sudo` closes all descriptors except 0-2, I tested `sudo konsole`, and the instance of `zsh` inside this new terminal doesn't leak descriptor `47` into new processes. This means that there's nothing wrong with Konsole itself, but that it receives the descriptor from its parent (which appears to be `plasmashell`).

Comment: Errr ??? I just cannot confirm this despite running Konsole under KDE-Plasma. But… I can remember (from a loooonng time ago) fds (47,48,49…) opened by the qt-webengine disgracefully leaking. Could you please provide more infos regarding kde-plasma, kde frameworks & Qt versions.

Comment: I am running `kde-plasma` 5.27.10, `kde-framework5` 5.114.0 and `qt5-base` 5.15.12 (from pacman). EDIT: `qt5-webengine` 5.15.16

Comment: `sudo lsof -d 47` may help spot which process in your shell's ancestry has opened that fd and forgot to mark it with the close-on-exec flag (or close it before executing another command).

Comment: @Bib Every program run by the shell gets this descriptor. Even if I write a C program from scratch it still has descriptor 47 opened it if it is run from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly special about FD 47.  At least, nothing standard.

When a file descriptor is opened, a flag can be set indicating if it should be closed or not on an exec() call to another program.  Most programs ignore any open file descriptors above the first 3 (and sometimes 4), so if something left one open and marked it to stay open across exec, it could stay open through multiple programs.  Very likely, it was left open by mistake; this is a file descriptor leak bug.  It might be tricky to trace it back to what left it open, especially considering what left it open may not be running anymore.

You might not see it open from a shell in a terminal because some shells meticulously close all extraneous open file descriptors in the interests of cleaning up as part of their initialization.  Leaking file descriptors unintentionally could be a security vulnerability, as the leaked FD could carry data that could be leaked unintentionally to another program.

This would be especially dangerous when changing users, so it makes sense for sudo to close anything extra.

Comment: Normally a shell shouldn't leave any descriptors (aside the standard 0-2) open to the program it executes. Leaking descriptors like this can be a security problem if it wasn't done intentionally. I have already traced the process which initially leaked the descriptor (it is `plasmashell` which was started by `systemd`), so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Good call, I'll add that.

Comment: @DarkAtom your question: "What is file descriptor 47 used for". You provide yourself the answer: " have already traced the process which initially leaked the descriptor (it is plasmashell which was started by systemd)". This is the answer to the question. You appear to have changed the goal of your question into "Why does a shell keep file descriptors opened?" which is an entirely different question. "Normally a shell shouldn't leave any descriptors" is debatable, not to be assumed as a postulate.